# Is the equality correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, stirling-numbers

Is it true that $f^k=(k-1)!/log^k(t)$ ? $k$ refers to the order of derivatives and  $f(t)=logt$.If yes, then how can i show this? I've been doing different ways just to solve it but i cant get the right one. Can someone help me?

Comment: If $f(t)=\ln t$ then $f^{(1)}(t)=\frac {1}{x} \ne \frac {1}{\ln (x)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not the case.  Notice that

$f'(x)=\frac1x$

$f''(x)=-\frac1{x^2}$

$\vdots$

$f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(n-1)!}{x^k}$

So you were close, but not quite there.